# Decode text from a FOR XML Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Say I'm using a FOR XML sub query to allow concatenation and sorting, and in addition, the data contains angle brackets:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + '<' + NAME + '>'
          FROM   [sys].[login_token]
          ORDER  BY NAME
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Logins;
```

The output is something like

```
&lt;\Everyone&gt;, &lt;BUILTIN\Administrators&gt;, &lt;BUILTIN\Administrators&gt;
```

How can I have it decoded, that is, something like this:

```
<\Everyone>, <BUILTIN\Administrators>, <BUILTIN\Administrators>,
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a query on the XML and return a converted value!

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + '<' + NAME + '>'
          FROM   [sys].[login_token]
          ORDER  BY NAME
          FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
          , 1, 2, '') AS Logins;
```

You add `, type` to the `FOR XML PATH` specification, then a `.value` with an XQuery expression and data type to convert to! See MSDN Here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work with Substring for some reason, only works with STUFF. Any ideas why?

Comment: The stuff just strips the leading comma, if you replace it with Substring you need to fix up the parameters, eg. you want SUBSTRING( [selectfunction],  3, 10000) to start at character 3 to remove the comma and return the next 10000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use 2 `replace` functions:

```
SELECT replace(replace(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + '<' + NAME + '>'
          FROM   [sys].[login_token]
          ORDER  BY NAME
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>') AS Logins;
```